# Why process substitution doesn’t work in a script?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

A simple line

```
$ read a b < <(sed -nr '$ s/.*(123).*(456).*/\1 \2/p' <<<"fds 123 fdsf 456 f")
$ echo $a - $b
123 - 456
```

works in a terminal, but being put in a script

```
$ echo -e '#!/bin/bash\nread a b < <(sed -nr '$ s/.*(123).*(456).*/\1 \2/p' <<<"fds 123 fdsf 456 f")\necho $a - $b' >/tmp/t
$ chmod +x /tmp/t
$ /tmp/t
```

it gives an error

```
/tmp/t: command substitution: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/tmp/t: command substitution: line 3: `sed -nr $ s/.*(123).*(456).*/1 2/p <<<"fds 123 fdsf 456 f")'
```

I suspect that it’s somehow related with the stdin of the script that `read` cannot access for some reason, but I couldn’t figure out what exactly does it need.

---

I’ve made a mistake in the example I made to write to a file, but it’s unrealted to the problem. Assume that the line with `read` looks exactly alike in both terminal and script versions. The question is why it doesn’t work being put in a file.

Comment: Did you open your file `/tmp/t` to inspect its content? you'll see it's not what you're expecting (problem with quotes and backslashed characters).

Comment: "Thats a mistake ...", "I am not writing to a file in the actual script" .... "I've made a mistake in the example". Please fix your question to show your real problem. If  you're doing debugging writing to `/tmp/t`, then write a separate paragraph explaining that. Good luck.

Comment: You are prematurely closing the single-quoted string with the single quote in the `sed` command. They do not nest.

Comment: I believe the actual question is quite different from the question as given.  And I think the answer is that the `<()` syntax is not portable, and the shell that you are invoking with your script does not recognize it.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I run it on localhost, with the same shell. Btw glad to see someone finally looking in the root of the actual problem. Too bad it happened after I posted solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I still don’t get why the process substitution did not work, this workaround helped me

```
read a b <<EOF
$(sed -nr '$ s/.*(123).*(456).*/\1 \2/p' <<<"fds 123 fdsf 456 f")
EOF
```

You may need to specify IFS before sed, like

```
$(IFS=' '; sed -nr '$ s/.*(123).*(456).*/\1 \2/p' <<<"fds 123 fdsf 456 f")
```

for this example.

Answer (score 2):

You're not writing the script correctly.  The easiest way to do things like this is with a heredoc:

```
cat > /tmp/t << \EOF
#!/bin/bash
read a b < <(sed -nr '$ s/.*(123).*(456).*/\1 \2/p' <<<"fds 123 fdsf 456 f")
echo $a - $b
EOF
chmod +x /tmp/t
/tmp/t
```

Comment: I am not writing to a file in the actual script. The line with `read` is what doesn’t work.

Comment: @tijagi The script (/tmp/t) generated by this command also does not write to a file.  I do not understand your comment.

Answer (score 2):

You are using *process substitution* in two completely different quoting scenarios. First:

```
read a b < <(sed -nr '$ s/.*(123).*(456).*/\1 \2/p' <<<"fds 123 fdsf 456 f")
```

Here you are using *process substitution* to feed the results to `read`:

```
sed -nr '$ s/.*(123).*(456).*/\1 \2/p' <<<"fds 123 fdsf 456 f"
```

to your read statement -- which is fine. There are no quoting issues present. (however your use of a *herestring* when simple redirection should do is suspect).

In your second command line/script attempt:

```
$ echo -e '#!/bin/bash\nread a b < <(sed -nr '$ s/.*(123).*(456).*/\1 \2/p' <<<"fds 123 fdsf 456 f")\necho
```

You are improperly using *single-quotes* which terminates your command early leaving it incomplete. Replace your second set of single-quotes with *double-quotes* (or vice-versa):

```
echo -e '#!/bin/bash\nread a b < <(sed -nr "$ s/.*(123).*(456).*/\1 \2/p" <<<"fds 123 fdsf 456 f")\necho'
```

`echo` knows nothing of process substitution, it only knows when it has an open single quote `'`, then then next one should be a closing single quote...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the quoting, use this to write the script:

```
cat <<'EOF' >script
#!/bin/bash
read a b < <(sed -nr '$ s/.*(123).*(456).*/\1 \2/p' <<<"fds 123 fdsf 456 f")
echo $a $b
EOF
```

The quote in the here-document `<<'EOF'` disables parameter expansion in the script.

Comment: That’s a mistake I made, but that was just an example, the actual line I have problem with has the quotes.